# diagramming a N-AV-n-N sentence

Tags: diagramming

Can you please diagram this sentence for me?

Each brother contributed his particular talent to the project.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We have no diagramming tools, and homework requests of this nature are likely to be closed as they would not be helpful to future visitors. If you have a specific question about the usage, sentence structure, or parts of speech, however, we may be able to help you.

Comment: However, it's a pretty simple sentence. [Each brother] is the subject, [contributed his particular talent to the project] is the verb phrase. The verb phrase consists of a verb [contributed], a direct object [hiw particular talent], and a prepositional phrase [to the project] (which functions as an indirect object, but does not undergo dative movement). The subject, the direct object, and the object of the prepositional phrase are all noun phrases.

Comment: The sentence structure is someone contributed sth to sth. Does a diagram make it any clearer?  But I don't understand  your cryptic formula N AV etc.

Answer (score -1):

*"Each brother contributed his particular talent to the project."*

```
sbj: brother
        det: each
vrb: contributed
        obj: talent
                det: his
                adj: particular
        adv: <to>
                obj: project
                        det: the
```

see [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272720/a-simple-alternative-to-reed-kellogg-diagrams-suggestions-and-criticisms-neede) for key to the diagram